# My modal view controller didn't appeared on the screen. UITabbar + navigation app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

UITabbar + navigation app. My modal controllerNav didn't appeared on the screen. What is wrong?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

  if (isLoginScreenNeeded)
   {    
    LoginModalViewController *controller = [[[LoginModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginModal" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *controllerNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:controllerNav animated:NO];
    }

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

EDIT: @Zoleas, I updated my code. If I will remove [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; - it works. But I don't understand why do I need to remove self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `parentViewController` from the line `[self.window.rootViewController.parentViewController presentModalViewController:controllerNav animated:NO];`

the `UITabBarController` is the `rootViewController` so it probably doesn't have a `parentViewController`.

Comment: I removed parentViewController but it didn't helped me.

Comment: Are you sure that all your controllers are non nil? Can you log self.tabBarController, controller, and controllerNav before trying to present your modalViewController?

Answer (score 0):

map your main.xib files view to the rootViewcontrollers view .. then it will work

Comment: I updated my code. I needed to present modalVC when  isLoginScreenNeeded = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following code for mapping

```
[map from:kAppViewController toModalViewController:[controller class]];
```

Comment: We use Three20 Library                                    TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
 
    
 navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeTop;
 
 TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;

Answer (score 0):

I have found that makeKeyAndVisible removes the Modal view from the parent so remove the line `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`
or you can move it to the top.